# Redis Graph compilation on macOS

Tags: xcode, redis, llvm, llvm-clang, redisgraph

I am getting below error when I compile RedisGraph from https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redis-graph.git

Error is

> [  0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/graphblas.dir/Source/GB_AxB_builtin.c.o
>   In file included from /Users/tkhader/codeBase/redis/redis-graph/deps/GraphBLAS/Source/GB_AxB_builtin.c:19:
>   /Users/tkhader/codeBase/redis/redis-graph/deps/GraphBLAS/Source/GB.h:1527:1: error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current target
>   _Thread_local extern GB_thread_local_struct GB_thread_local ;

svc-notes-MacBook-Pro:redis-graph tkhader$ llvm-gcc -v
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Let me know if u need more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest starting from scratch, delete and reclone,
go to the GraphBLAS dependancy directory and try to build GraphBLAS as a library, 'make library', once GraphBLAS is built, return to RedisGraph root directory and run make.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redis-graph/issues/20

1. Run make install from within the deps/GraphBLAS folder
2. Update src/Makefile to dynamically link GraphBLAS:
   redisgraph.so: $(MODULE)
   $(LD) -o $@ $(MODULE) $(SHOBJ_LDFLAGS) -lc -lm -lgraphblas
   Remove GRAPHBLAS from LIBS.

Comment: I saw that swilly22 had commented he changed  Makefiles so I ignored that, but it still gives me same error while I make install GraphBLAS :
> [  0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/graphblas.dir/Source/GB_AxB_builtin.c.o
In file included from /Users/tkhader/codeBase/redis/redis-graph/deps/GraphBLAS/Source/GB_AxB_builtin.c:19:
/Users/tkhader/codeBase/redis/redis-graph/deps/GraphBLAS/Source/GB.h:1527:1: error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current target
_Thread_local extern GB_thread_local_struct GB_thread_local ;
^
1 error generated.